# XeLaTeX: WordInitial, Inner and WordFinal seem to match everywhere

Tags: xetex, characters, opentype

I am creating a blackletter font and would like to use it with XeLaTeX. I try to use initial/medial/final substitution for letters, like s/ſ, but the context seems to match even when it should not.

For example, I try to execute substitution of s by ſ using the `init` and `medi` tables, but with `fontspec` and `Contextuals={Inner}`, word-initial and -final “s”es are replaced by “ſ”, too. The corresponding applies for all substitutions of initial and final forms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Script=Latin,Language=German,Contextuals=Inner}
\setmainfont{Jena1330.otf}
\begin{document}
smstsms
\end{document}
```

gives a document containing ſmſtſmſ in the correct font, instead of smſtſms, as I would expect.

Am I doing something wrong? How does XeLaTeX decide if a letter is initial, medial or final?

Comment: I ignored this problem now by making Jena1330 fit for vanilla pdfLaTeX, by using a manually generated pl/tfm file. (`.`, `,` and so on are still considered part of the word there, though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most OpenType layout engine handle `isol`/`init`/`medi`/`fina` properly only for specific scripts (Arabic, Syriac, Mongolian, etc.), for other scripts they will apply them unconditionally, which seems to be the case with the [ICU layout engine](http://userguide.icu-project.org/layoutengine) used by XeTeX. AFAIK, only some Adobe applications handle them for Latin script.

For better compatibility, you should implement it using contextual substitutions.

Comment: So for compatibility with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX I have to implement them as both `calt` and `init`/`medi`/`fina`, since LuaLaTeX has a problem with `calt`, but supports the in-word contexts for Latin script.

Comment: I'm surprised that they work with LuaLaTeX, AFAIK as I know it doesn’t, the `calt` issue might be a bug, but without the actual font I can’t help much.

Comment: They _mostly_ work with LuaLaTex. As in [this other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15332/trouble-with-contextuals-in-lualatex-with-fontspec-trying-to-get-internal-long), I see that “…s,” is replaced by “…ſ,”, even though “,” is not a letter.