# Contextual Alternatives in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, opentype

I am creating a blackletter font and would like to use it with LuaLaTeX, which works fine for nearly everything so far, except for using contextual alternative glyphs (in this case, r→ꝛ after round letters).

Ousia reports that as a [bug](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/130) for `fontspec`, and gets the answer that it seems to be a bug in `luaotfload`. Is there a workaround or bugfix somewhere out there?

Comment: Is the issue loading contextual alternative glyphs for any font or for the one mentioned in the bug report (Theano Didot). I have found that `fontspec` can be a bit temperamental when it comes to loading alternative glyphs. For example, I can't call alternative glyphs of Linux Libertine with `Alternate=0`, but have to use `Style=Alternate` instead.

Comment: I've downloaded `Theano Didot` and according to Photoshop's font selection it does not have alternative glyphs.

Comment: I did not try it with Theano Didot (I just linked to that bug report because it looks like the same problem) but with a font I'm working on myself, and I definitely want to use the `calt` table, which should be activated by `Contextuals=Alternate` or `RawFeature={+calt}` (as in that bugreport), both of which did nothing.

Comment: Which font are you using?

Comment: The one I generate from https://github.com/Anaphory/Jena1330 with fontforge...

Comment: Okay, I've tried with `Junicode` that loads the `calt` table by default, and unfortunately that bug still exists in luaotfload 1.27. So it appears you would have to use `XeLaTeX`. Have you tried reviving this issue on the LuaTeX Mailing List?

Comment: I have not yet got round to asking there. And with XeLaTeX I had the problem described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55452/xelatex-wordinitial-inner-and-wordfinal-seem-to-match-everywhere that it does not easily allow me to use the `init`, `medi` aso. tables, so I would have to add or change all such replacements to contextual alternates. (I would so much prefer if one of these two engines could do both…)

Comment: I'm trying to work around this problem now by making Jena1330 fit for vanilla pdfLaTeX (I hadn't thought that would be the easiest flavour to use it with…), by changing the pl/tfm file. Mostly works, automation (for possible other fonts and later versions) and `ſ,` instead of `s,` and similar cases are still unsolved.

Comment: @Anaphory: Any progress with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX? Did you try the recent versions of xetex/luatex?